# Error Karma 'undefined' scope variable in beforeEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Here are my 2 files and error. I am running Karma, here is my karma.conf.js: https://gist.github.com/devanp92/a87c0bcc2bf5b8e17f64. After running 'karma start' I get this error. It is a very simple test file (or so I assume) and I am still getting these errors.

Main.js - This is a controller

```
angular.module('SSLApp').controller('MainCtrl',  
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.thing = 1;
});
```

MainSpec.js - This is my test file

```
describe('MainCtrl', function() {
var controller, scope;

beforeEach(angular.module('SSLApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should have scope to be defined', function(scope) {
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();
});

});
```

ERROR! It looks like it is being called undefined in the var MainCtrl = $controller...

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'queueableFn.fn.call(self.userContext)')
        at /Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:184
        at `http://localhost:9876/karma.js:185`
        at `http://localhost:9876/context.html:53`
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at assertArg (/Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1577)
        at assertArgFn (/Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1588)
        at /Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8418
        at /Users/BLAH/Documents/test/controllers/MainSpec.js:9
        at invoke (/Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4182)
        at workFn (/Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2350)
        at /Users/BLAH/Documents/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:184
        at http://localhost:9876/karma.js:185
        at http://localhost:9876/context.html:53
    undefined
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (4.999 secs / 5.012 secs)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your test code.

First of all you use wrong *module* function. The [angular.module()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) function provides a real framework module while 
simple **module()** is an alias for [angular.mock.module()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module) which you should use in tests. So you ought to write your *beforeEach* function as follows:

```
beforeEach(module('SSLApp'));
```

Besides, you defined the test case function with a parameter but it should be parameterless. The `scope` variable is accessible from the outer scope.

```
it('should have scope to be defined', function() {
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: For those running karma with a webpack configuration, I recommend use `angular.mock.module` instead of `module` because global `module` will be pointing to node's module.