# TypeError: scope is undefined Karma-jasmine-angular unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new with **karma-jasmine** and trying to develop a demo test case. I am getting error of **scope is not defined** in **'it'**. I have read the following links with same problem but it's not helping me with my test case.

[Error Karma 'undefined' scope variable in beforeEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630899/error-karma-undefined-scope-variable-in-beforeeach)

[TypeError: $scope is undefined in Angular controller unit test with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849953/typeerror-scope-is-undefined-in-angular-controller-unit-test-with-jasmine)

> This is my **karma.conf.js**

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({

    exclude)
        basePath: '',


        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

     files: [
          'js/angular.js',
          'js/angular-mocks.js',
          'app.js',
          'test/**/*Spec.js'
        ],
        exclude: [
        ],

        preprocessors: {
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

    config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        autoWatch: false,


        browsers: ['Firefox'],

        singleRun: false 
      });
    };
```

> Here is my **mySpec.js** where test code is written

```
describe('myApp', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe('HelloWorldController', function() {

        var scope,HelloWorldController;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            HelloWorldController = $controller('HelloWorldController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it('should assign message to hello world', function () {
            expect(scope.greeting).toEqual('Hello World!');
        });
    });
});
```

> And this is my **app.js** where controller is defined.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('HelloWorldController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello World!';
}]);
```

The error which I get is,

> TypeError: scope is undefined in**
>   /home/abc/WebstormProjects/test1/test/basic/mySpec.js (line 17)

I don't have any idea of where I am making mistake. Please guide me toward this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what was the actual problem but when I install angular files using bower it resolve my problem. So It is possible that if you didn't install your angular files using bower than it might not work. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Unit Test - Scope undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928231/angularjs-unit-test-scope-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems here was a typo. 'scope' was undefined, because in your controller injection, you defined it as '$scope', but your expect statement referenced 'scope':

```
describe('myApp', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe('HelloWorldController', function() {

        var scope,HelloWorldController;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            HelloWorldController = $controller('HelloWorldController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it('should assign message to hello world', function () {
            expect(scope.greeting).toEqual('Hello World!');
        });
    });
});
```